# How to replace a string of the form: [Unknown Location #123456789] in a dataframe with another string?

Tags: python, regex, dataframe

I have a dataframe where several of the columns can contain the string: [Unknown Location #123456789], so let's say one of the columns looks like this:

```
0       Denmark
1       Sweden
2       Norway
3       Denmark
4       Denmark
5       Finland
6       Sweden
7       Norway
8       [Unknown Location #123456789]
```

I have tried to figure out a way to replace the string [Unknown Location #123456789] with a new string but I cannot seem to get anything to recognize the whole string and substitute it with a new string. I have tried

```
data[7].str.replace("[Unknown Location #123456789]", 'Iceland', regex=True)
data[7].replace(to_replace='[Unknown Location #123456789]', value='Iceland')
data[7].replace('[Unknown Location #123456789]', 'Iceland')
```

which all compiles, but does nothing. I feel like regex is a huge mystery at this point so if anyone can help me with an expression that can do this I would be very grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two options:

1. Using the *in place* parameter:

```
data.replace(to_replace='[Unknown Location #123456789]', value='Iceland', inplace=True)
```

2. Using the version that returns the copy but update the dataframe:

```
data = data.replace(to_replace='[Unknown Location #123456789]', value='Iceland')
```

Docs here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

Comment: Your first option worked flawlessly, guess I was almost there. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

"[" is a pattern of regular expressions. if you want to use one word, you can use "\".

```py
> data = ["Denmark", "Sweden", "Norway", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Finland", "Sweden", "Norway", "[Unknown Location #123456789]"]
> df = pd.Series(data).to_frame()
> df.columns = ["location"]
> df
    location
0   Denmark
1   Sweden
2   Norway
3   Denmark
4   Denmark
5   Finland
6   Sweden
7   Norway
8   [Unknown Location #123456789]
```

you can use this

```py
> df["location"].str.replace("\[Unknown Location #123456789\]", "Iceland", regex=True)
> df["location"]
0    Denmark
1     Sweden
2     Norway
3    Denmark
4    Denmark
5    Finland
6     Sweden
7     Norway
8    Iceland
Name: 0, dtype: object
```